# Image not found after ClickOnce publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, migradoc

I am creating a PDF document, using MigraDoc. The image is located in the root folder of the project, so I use this code to insert it in the PDF-document:

```
Image img = tfLogoDate.AddImage("../../db_logo_500p.png");
```

The Build Action is set to 'Content':

[image: Properties of the image file.]

This works fine during development, using the Visual Studio debug build. But when I create a build with ClickOnce (publish), it says that the image is not found.

[image: MigraDoc: Image not found.]

Am I using the wrong Build Action? Or is it because the relative path changes, when I use ClickOnce to publish my application?

Comment: In the image, 'Copy to Output Directory' is set to 'Do Not Copy'.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane yes, but I am not sure what this actually means. Because when I look in the folder where it is installed, the graphics file is there (still in the root).

Comment: When you build the project, this setting dictates whether or not the files get copied to the bin folder. Check in it, the file should be missing.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I have tried chaning the `Copy to Output Directory` setting to 'Copy Always', but it had no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work, by changing the image location. I now use this instead:

```
// I have added the 'pack://(...)' in front of the path
Image img = tfLogoDate.AddImage("pack://application:,,,/../../db_logo_500p.png");
```

I had to use the following settings for the PNG-file:

- Build Action: **Content**
- Copy to Output Directory: **Do not copy**

If anyone knows exactly why the above works, I would be delighted to know. But the most important thing is, that it works...

Comment: The image is compiled into your assembly. Initially you were using the image from the project folder - and this, of course, only worked before the deployment when the application was launched from the project folder.

Comment: So basically, you are saying that the `pack://application:,,,/` references, kind of changes, depending on the build/publish method?

Comment: You reference an image file that is embedded as a resource in your assembly. Fine if it works for you. Good for static images - makes it more difficult for users to replace the image. Bad if users should be able to customize the logo.